# Define variable to set dynamic location and filename of a pdf to look for an open

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting using excel vba to shortcut a regular process, in which a user will find a specific pdf, and open it to allow some updating using a pdf editor.  The filename is specified in an excel worksheet and will be dynamic.

(I may later want to dynamically update this file, but lets keep it simple for the moment - as even simply appears beyond me at for now).

I have tried a few bits of code but keep getting run time errors or type mismatch.

Here is my current code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TNR Update")
Dim r As Range: Set r = ws.Range("A82") ' this defines the actual path and filename to be searched for
Dim Hyperlink As String: Hyperlink = r.Value

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink
```

(this last bit is where I run aground - no matter what I add in here it doesn't work or appears to be totally wrong)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: add `r.value` or `hyperlink` to that line.  Press `F1` to reveal the help on this.  On a side note, it's best to keep variables away from keywords or reserved words, so `strHyperlink`

Comment: Reading the documentation helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add

Comment: Nathan, I tried r.value to the hyperlink line and that's where I got the type mismatch error, I tired hyerlink also and the same occurred.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TNR Update")
Dim r As Range: Set r = ws.Range("A82") ' this defines the actual path and filename to be searched for

Dim strHyperlink As String

strHyperlink = r.Value

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strHyperlink
```

The above tested fine on my machine. If it's still erroring, check the path that you've got in `A82` as it may be invalid.

Comment: CLR, thanks - I am a proper idiot.  I had the wrong blooming worksheet referenced - no wonder my original code wouldn't work - it was looking into a blank cell!